# Clearing Layouts without deleting widgets

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I currently have a vertical layout that hosts multiple layouts that have widgets inside them.Now I want to remove all the layouts inside that vertical layout. Currently I am using the following method. Which clears the layout in the ui. The problem is this method only clears the ui when the deleteWidgets parameter in the method is true otherwise the ui is not cleared (The items are still in the layout). Any suggestions on how I could clear the layout without deleting the widgets.

I then used the following code

```
while(layout->count() != 0)
    {
        layout->removeItem( layout->itemAt(0));
    }
```

Now when I call the count on the layout the items are 0. However the layout still seems to have the items there at the ui ? Why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to do with the widgets? If you don't wish to delete them you should change there parent, either by putting them in a new layout if you still want to show them or moving them to the parent and hide them.  If you are doing the later it would be best to keep member variables with pointers maybe in a list, but the following adaptation of your code should work presuming foo inherits QWidget, although storing the widgets and manipulating them directly will be a better solution.

```
void foo::clearLayout(QLayout* layout, bool deleteWidgets)
{
    while (QLayoutItem* item = layout->takeAt(0))
    {
        if (QWidget* widget = item->widget())
        {            
            if (deleteWidgets)
            {
                delete widget;
            }
            else
            {
                // note you will need to call show on this widget
                // before it is visible again.
                widget->setParent(this);
            }

        if (QLayout* childLayout = item->layout())
             clearLayout(childLayout, deleteWidgets);

        delete item;
    }
}
```

Also your example above doesn't handle spacer items.

A basic example of doing it the other way (not guaranteed to compile)

**Foo.h**

```
#include <QWidget>

// Forward declare classes that will be used
class QLabel;
class QPushButton;

class foo: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

     explicit foo(QWidget * parent);

public slots:
     void swapToVLayout();
     void swapToHLayout();

private:
     void clearLayout(QLayout* layout);

private:
     QLabel * label;
     QLabel * label2;
     QPushButton * button;
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>

#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

#include "foo.h"

foo::foo(parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    label = new QLabel();
    label2 = new QLabel();
    button = new button();

    QHBoxLayout * layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(label);

    QVBoxLayout * layout2 = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout2->addWidget(label2);
    layout2->addWidget(button);

    layout->addLayout(layout2);

    setLayout(layout);
}

void foo::setVLayout()
{
    clearLayout(layout(), false);

    QVBoxLayout * vLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    vLayout->addWidget(label);
    vLayout->addWidget(label2);
    vLayout->addWidget(button);

    setLayout(vLayout);
}
```

That's a very basic example that probably could be done better, but hopefully sends you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks what happens if I want to move them back to their original location ?

Comment: That is where it would be better to keep a private member variable somewhere so that you can re add it to a widget later, i'll add a quick example of that approach to the example